# Learning python and dealing with lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a list of lists, and within the nested lists are tuples (representative of (x,y) coordinates). I want the nested lists to represent a bin. At the end of this, I want to put this data into Mathematica. That is why I'm generating the points like this.

```
list_of_list = [[(2,1),(4,2),(3,1)], [(1,1),(2,2),(4,3)]]
```

I want to separate the x-coordinates and the y-coordinates, but I each of the nested lists to be two different stacks of boxes (referring back to the two different bins). So, essentially, I want to plot the boxes. Also, in my actual code I generate N amount of boxes, so I will be dealing with more than one nested list.

How can I make it resemble this:

```
x = [[2,4,3],[1,2,4]]

y = [[1,2,1],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: For step 2, I'm not sure what you mean by "shifted over".  Are you saying you want to add some deltax and deltay to each point?

Comment: That is what I meant, but I deleted that part of the question until I can find a better way with my words to explain

Comment: That is a reasonable thing to do, but if you ask a follow-up question, let's make sure that your input and output formats actually describe your real data.  For example, will it always be a list of lists of tuples?  If you ask detailed questions, we can give productive answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

```
>>> x = [[l[0] for l in  m] for m  in list_of_list]
>>> x
[[2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
>>> y = [[l[1] for l in  m] for m  in list_of_list]
>>> y
[[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `zip` and iterable unpacking:

```
list_of_list = [[(2,1),(4,2),(3,1)], [(1,1),(2,2),(4,3)]]
x, y = zip(*(zip(*item) for item in list_of_list))
print(x)
print(y)
```

output

```
((2, 4, 3), (1, 2, 4))
((1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3))
```

Second part of your question is quite unclear and (i) it will be better to focus on single question/problem and (ii) there is chance the first part is XY problem - i.e. if it's clear what your ultimate goal is, there might be better approach that don't require the first step.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I deleted the second part of the question since I worded it incorrectly. I'm going to toy around with it for a while!

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method which groups by coordinates, which is a bit verbose but self explanatory, for example:

```
def group_by_x_and_y(points):
    xs = [x for x, _ in points]
    ys = [y for _, y in points]
    return xs, ys
```

So, if you call `group_by_x_and_y(list_of_list[0])`, you get

```
#=> [[2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 1]]
```

Then you can use in this way for the required result:

```
xs, ys = group_by_x_and_y([group_by_x_and_y(coords) for coords in list_of_list])
xss #=> [[2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
yss #=> [[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

Another option is to use Numpy, which is not required by the OP, but maybe can give a further hint:

```
import numpy as np
coords = np.array(list_of_list)
np.transpose(coords)

#array([[[2, 1],
#        [4, 2],
#        [3, 4]],
#
#       [[1, 1],
#        [2, 2],
#        [1, 3]]])
```

Then slice as you need.